# ¿Cómo puedo crear una tabla pivote con una columna que combine dos columnas ya existentes?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Actualmente me encuentro en una encrucijada desarrollando un QUERY.

Tengo una tabla que está guardando campos como *subcuenta*,*valor*, *id_mes*, *mes*, *anio* y *empresa*. Estos están distribuidos de forma vertical.

```
  subcuenta    valor          id_mes     mes     anio    empresa
+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+
|    110505 | 894.00        |      2 | Febrero | 2019 | EMPRESA 1    |
|    111005 | 252.00        |      1 | Enero   | 2019 | EMPRESA 1    |
|    110505 | 5892.00       |      2 | Febrero | 2019 | EMPRESA 2    |
|    111005 | 0.00          |      1 | Enero   | 2019 | EMPRESA 2    |
|    110505 | 9852.00       |      2 | Febrero | 2019 | EMPRESA 3    |
|    111005 | 11430100.00   |      1 | Enero   | 2019 | EMPRESA 3    |
|    120505 | 11314500.00   |      2 | Febrero | 2019 | EMPRESA 4    |
|    120505 | 0.00          |      1 | Enero   | 2019 | EMPRESA 4    |
+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------------+
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que la `empresa - mes` se unan y formen una columna y como valor de la columna el valor.

Anteriormente logré hacer algo parecido con tablas pivote pero era solo con una empresa, entonces funcionaba, pero ahora no logro hacerlo con diferentes empresas.

Deseo un resultado como el siguiente:

```
subcuenta   EMPRESA 1 Enero   EMPRESA 1 Febrero   EMPRESA 2 Enero    EMPRESA 2 Febrero    EMPRESA 3 Enero    EMPRESA 3 Febrero   Empresa 4 Enero      Empresa 4 Febrero
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  110505   |    0.00         |       894.00      |      0.00       |      5892.00    |      0.00        |    9852.00       |      0.00          |          0.00        |
|  111005   |    252.00       |       0.00        |      0.00       |      0.00           |      11430100.00 |    0.00          |      0.00          |          0.00        |
|  120505   |    0.00         |       0.00        |      0.00       |      0.00           |      0.00        |    0.00          |      0.00          |          11314500.00 |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Si se escoge más meses deben aparecer ejemplo:

- EMPRESA 1 Enero
- Empresa 1 Febrero
- Empresa 1 Marzo

Y así sucesivamente, y si no encuentra esa subcuenta colocar por defecto en el valor 0.00 y no dejarlo como null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes construir tu tabla pivote de este modo:

```
SELECT subcuenta,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Enero" AND empresa = "Empresa 1" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Enero1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Febrero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 1" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Enero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 2" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Enero2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Febrero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 2" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Enero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 3" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Enero3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Febrero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 3" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Enero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 4" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Enero4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mes = "Febrero"  AND empresa = "Empresa 4" THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero4
FROM demo
GROUP BY subcuenta;
```

**Aclaraciones**

- Hacemos uso de la función `SUM()` para envolver cada uno de los `CASE`, entonces estaríamos sumando los valores, pero como por cada mes y tipo de empresa solo hay un registro; entonces solo mostrará el número sin alterar su valor
- Usamos la sentencia `CASE` para crear un flujo de condiciones, a través de las cuales se evalúen distintas condiciones que de cumplirse retornen un resultado

  - El mes debe ser igual a uno en específico
  - La empresa debe ser igual a cada una de las 4 que están declaradas
- Agrupamos por la columna de `subcuenta`
- Para poder mostrar un 0 si no existe una cantidad asignada, en el `ELSE` establecemos que retorne 0

**Muestra de los resultados**

[Enlace al ejercicio funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1de1b87533bc525974cc6339f337d715)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cambié el título a _¿Cómo puedo crear una tabla pivote con una columna que combine dos columnas ya existentes?_ No sabía que se denominara _tabla pivote_ a este caso. En cualquier caso, modifica lo que consideres, la idea es que se explique mejor el título

Comment: Agradecido infinitamente @fedorqui

Comment: ¿Que pasa si son elegidos más de 4 empresas?