# Como pasar filas a columnas en SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Tengo una tabla con algunos registros como la siguiente:

```
| id|tipo    |activo|
|---|--------|------|
|  1|caso    |si    |
|  2|sospecha|si    |
|  3|caso    |no    |
```

Lo que busca es contabilizar los casos, sospecha y activos pero no logro dar con la forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.tipo) 
FROM TB_EPISODIO_TB e WHERE e.tipo ='caso'
```

Eso que he probado solo me trae la cantidad de casos, entonces pensaba si era posible pasar la columna a fila y tener algo así:

```
|caso    |sospecha| activos|
|--------|--------| si     |
|2       |1       | 2
```

Comment: Necesitas hacer una tabla pivote, di una respuesta aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267642/duda-mysql-pivot/267684#267684 y aunque es para mysql te sirve para tu gestor pues ya hice una prueba

Comment: Podrias revisar lo siguiente: https://gist.github.com/waylan/6555316