# Ordenar una tabla por dias de la semana

Tags: java, mysql

estoy tratando de generar una tabla utilizando MySQL y como llaves tengo IdDoctor, IdDia, Dia, HorarioI, HorarioF, por ejemplo:

```
________ ______ _________________ __________ __________
IdDoctor|IdDia | Dia             | HorarioI | HorarioF |
1          1     Lunes              8:00        9:00
1          3     Miercoles         10:00       11:00
```

Pero necesito reacomodarla para que quede de la siguiente manera y no se si sea posible
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He modificado el store, de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT IdMedico,IdDia, 
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(IdDia=1, CONCAT(HoraInicio, '-', HoraFin), NULL)) Lunes,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(IdDia=2, CONCAT(HoraInicio, '-', HoraFin), NULL)) Martes,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(IdDia=3, CONCAT(HoraInicio, '-', HoraFin), NULL)) Miercoles,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(IdDia=4, CONCAT(HoraInicio, '-', HoraFin), NULL)) Jueves,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(IdDia=5, CONCAT(HoraInicio, '-', HoraFin), NULL)) Viernes
FROM ctgHorarioMedico where IdMedico = 3
GROUP BY IdDia;
```

Sin embargo este es el resultado que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que traducir tu pregunta, ya que es un SO en español.

Comment: Busca sobre tablas pivotantes...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo crear una tabla pivote con una columna que combine dos columnas ya existentes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267642/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-crear-una-tabla-pivote-con-una-columna-que-combine-dos-columnas-ya-e)

Comment: mira este blog:
https://firebird21.wordpress.com/tag/pivot-table/
es en firebird pero te puede dar la idea

Comment: Si y no, estuve buscando como agruparlos y creo que funciono, pero tengo un problema, ya que haora lo he puesto asi:

Comment: Las actualizaciones incluidos posibles errores agregalos en tu pregunta por favor

Comment: En tu tabla hay **un error de diseño** y los problemas que ahora tienes para resolver esto son en parte debido a ese error. Tus columnas `IdDia` y `Dia` **son redundantes**. Si declaras tus columnas `HorarioI` y `HorarioF` de tipo `DATETIME` ya tendrás en ellas el número de día que es, el nombre del día y **además podrás agrupar por fechas** que es el problema que tienes por el cual todos los datos te los trae en un *totum revolutum*. Sugiero entonces que normalices tu modelo de datos, si es posible, te ahorrarás espacio, dolores de cabeza y errores en los datos.