# MySQL Sumar discriminando por descripción

Tags: mysql, sql

gracias por pasar por acá.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

| id | producto | linea | cajas | empaque | costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manzana | 1 | 20 | Carton | 250 |
| 2 | Manzana | 1 | 15 | Plástico | 200 |
| 3 | Pera | 1 | 10 | Carton | 150 |
| 4 | Manzana | 2 | 10 | Plástico | 100 |
| 5 | Manzana | 1 | 15 | Carton | 200 |

Necesito la siguiente salida:

| linea | carton | plastico | costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 15 | 800 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 100 |

Lo intenté con un CASE (Cartón corresponde al empaque 1 y Plástico al 2)

```
            $procesos=Proceso::select('linea')
                    ->selectRaw('
                            (CASE
                            WHEN empaque=1 THEN sum(cajas)
                            ELSE 0
                            END)  as carton,
                            (CASE
                            WHEN empaque=2 THEN sum(cajas)
                            ELSE 0
                            END)  as plastico,
                            sum(costo) as totalCosto'
                        )
                    ->groupBy('linea')
                    ->orderBy('linea','ASC')
                    ->get();
```

El problema es que no puedo agrupar por caja porque me generaría una linea distinta por cada tipo de caja y al no agrupar queda todo sumado en la primera ocurrencia en la base de datos, quedando el total de cajas en los campos carton o plastico.

| linea | carton | plastico | costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 0 | 800 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 100 |

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consulta MySQL, de Filas a Columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309320/consulta-mysql-de-filas-a-columnas)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo crear una tabla pivote con una columna que combine dos columnas ya existentes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267642/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-crear-una-tabla-pivote-con-una-columna-que-combine-dos-columnas-ya-e)

Comment: O también [¿Cómo puedo convertir una cierta fila a una columna en mysql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/286412/16597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la *agregación condicional*, la condicionante va dentro de la función; y también puede hacerse con `if()`:

```
SELECT linea
     , sum( if(empaque='Carton',cajas,0) ) carton
     , sum( if(empaque='Plástico',cajas,0) ) plastico
     , sum( costo )
  FROM ( SELECT 1 id, 'Manzana' producto, 1 linea, 20 cajas, 'Carton' empaque, 250 costo
         UNION
         SELECT 2, 'Manzana', 1, 15, 'Plástico', 200
         UNION
         SELECT 3, 'Pera', 1, 10, 'Carton', 150
         UNION
         SELECT 4, 'Manzana', 2, 10, 'Plástico', 100
         UNION
         SELECT 5, 'Manzana', 1, 15, 'Carton', 200
       ) t
  GROUP BY linea
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el IF solucionó el problema de la agrupación, CASE no funciona si no se agrupa por el campo sobre el cual se está haciendo, IF no lo necesita.
El código quedó así:
            $procesos=Proceso::select('linea')
                    ->selectRaw('
                            (SUM(IF(empaque=1,cajas,0) AS carton,
                            (SUM(IF(empaque=2,cajas,0) AS plastico,
                            sum(costo) as totalCosto'
                        )
                    ->groupBy('linea')
                    ->orderBy('linea','ASC')
                    ->get();